# Javascript not update value of h:inputHidden

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

my javascipt function not set value of inputHIdden in bean.
maybe someone know the reason of this problem?

java

```
public String test = "";
//getter and setter
```

jsf

```
<h:inputHidden id="myInputHidden" value="#{bean.test}"/>
<p:commandButton value="Apply" actionListener="#{bean.filter}" onclick="set();"/>
```

javascript

```
 function set() {
        var str="test"
        $("#myForm\\:myInputHidden").val(str);
    }
```

Comment: are you sure about your selector ? try alert( $("#myForm\\:myInputHidden").length) ... also try `<p:commandButton process="@form"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
<p:commandButton value="Apply" actionListener="#{bean.filter}" onclick="#{bean.test}"/>
```

this way you don't need to have the JS function. If you want it to dinamically update add a Ajax call such as:

```
<f:ajax event="valueChange" render="@form" />
```

or

```
<f:ajax event="click" render="@form" />
```